# Multidimensional Array Implode

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, implode

Here is an example format of the multidimensional array I'm dealing with:

```
 Array ( 
    [1] => Array ( [code] => PPJ3 [street] => 34412 Fake Street [city] => Detroit [state] => MI [zip] => 48223 [county] => Wayne [cost] => 432.00 ) 

    [2] => Array ( [code] => PLK3 [street] => 73517 Fake Street [city] => Detroit [state] => MI [zip] => 48223 [county] => Wayne [cost] => 54.00 ) 

    [3] => Array ( [code] => HYK2 [street] => 55224 Fake Street [city] => Detroit [state] => MI [zip] => 48208 [county] => Wayne [cost] => 345.00 ) 
 )
```

I am trying to set a hidden field to only the code values and have it comma separated. The array would also need to be looped through because it will always change.
This is what I would like for it to look like:

$myHiddenField = PPJ3, PLK3, HYK2

What is a simple way of coding this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as long as you can reference the original array ..

> ```
> <?PHP
> $myHiddenField = array();
> foreach($array as $row) {
>     $myHiddenField [] = $row['code'];
> }
> ?>
> ```

or for a csv

> ```
> <?PHP
> foreach($array as $row) {
>     $myHiddenField .= ",".$row['code'];
> }
> $myHiddenField = substr($myHiddenField,1);
> ?>
> ```

Answer (score 2):

There will be [array_column](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/array_column) function is PHP 5.5, you will be able to do this

```
$myHiddenField = implode(',', array_column($yourMainArray, 'code'));
```

For now you have to use your own loop

```
$values = array();
foreach ($yourMainArray as $address)
{
  $values[] = $address['code'];
}
$myHiddenField = implode(',', $values);
```

Answer (score 0):

So what's wrong with using a loop ?

```
$myHiddenField = '';
$c = count($array);

for($i=0;$i<$c;$i++){
  if($i == $c -1){
     $myHiddenField .= $val['code'];
  }else{
     $myHiddenField .= $val['code'].', ';
  }
}
```

If you're using PHP 5.3+:

```
$tmp = array_map(function($v){return($v['code']);}, $array);
$myHiddenField = implode(', ', $tmp);
```